# Parsing output of chained dialog

Tags: bash, shell, sed, echo

I have a script generating 2 dialogs in chain and the output is a string of 2 numbers as such: "x y". I want to get those numbers in separate variables so I tried using sed:

```
y=$(echo -n $x | sed 's/\([0-9]\+\) \([0-9]*\)/\2/')
x=$(echo -n $x | sed 's/\([0-9]\+\) \([0-9]*\)/\1/')
```

Where $y is the output of the chained dialogs.
My issue is if I try each command in the terminal it works fine and "1 2" gives me x="1" and y="2" but from a bash shell script the variables have a space at the end (x="1 " and y="2 ").

```
echo -n "1 2" | sed 's/\([0-9]\+\) \([0-9]*\)/\2/' # Works
```

I have tried using tr to remove the space without effect. I also used 'echo -n' to remove the trailing newline but it does not change anything.
My goal is to make operations on these variables so they cannot have space at the end.

I print the result with:

```
echo -e 'x:"'$x'" ,y:"'$y'"'
```

I get the x variable as a result of:

```
x=$((dialog --clear --title title --menu Choose: 20 70 4 "1 a 2 b 3 c" \
  --and-widget --menu Choose: 20 70 4 "1 x 2 y 3 z") 2>&1)
```

Comment: Show all the relevant parts of the script including where you output the variables. They won't have spaces from what you have shown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
exec 3>&1
result=$( dialog --clear --title title --menu Choose: 20 70 4 1 a 2 b 3 c \
  --and-widget --menu Choose: 20 70 4 1 x 2 y 3 z  2>&1 1>&3 )
exitcode=$?
exec 3>&-
echo "result = >$result<" "exit-code = >$exitcode<"
sep=$(echo -e "\t") # define the separator
x=${result%$sep*} # remove up from separator
y=${result#*$sep} # remove up to separator

echo "Choosen: x=$x y=$y"
```

See https://askubuntu.com/questions/491509/how-to-get-dialog-box-input-directed-to-a-variable for getting the result of dialog into a variable. Your code `x=$((` indicates and arithmetic expansion, which is not properly finished. See `man bash` `$((expression))` Why it doesn't end with an error is beyond me. The quotes around dialogs parameters result in 5 parameters, while you need 4 parameters plus one or more pairs of parameters.

The result string from dialog seems to be separated by a TAB. Working with a regex based on blank would not work.

`sed` is not needed, it can be done with (bash builtin) 'Parameter Expansion'.

The menu is still printed on stdout. `exec 3>&1` creates a duplicate of stdout. `1>&3` directs the usual output to channel 3, which is a duplicate of 1. Normal output ends up in stdout.

`2>&1` redirects stderr to stdout which ends up as content of the variable.

In case of an error the error message is in your variable. Some error handling is needed.

Could not test with Xdialog, but I would expect it to work too.

Comment: This always results in "Choosen: x=1 y=2". In fact I'm using Xdialog, I just tested with dialog and it does not work since it needs stdout to print the menu.

Comment: So your answer provides a fix for that.

Comment: Sorry, changed that.  The parameter expansion was just completely wrong

Answer (score 1):

You can do this directly using Bash:

```
read x y <<< "1 2"
```

It will strip whitespace and set the variables $x and $y.

Comment: This works in the terminal but does not work for the dialog. I only get x, y is empty.

Comment: What is the string you are getting from the dialog exactly?

Comment: If I do "echo $x", I get something like "1 2" (without the quotes)

Comment: What if you say `echo A${x}B`, what EXACTLY do you get then?

Comment: I get "A1 2B" (without the quotes if the choice is 1 for the first dialog and 2 for the second one).

Comment: My guess is that dialog introduce some kind of special character that I cannot see in the shell. How would I go about printing that character?

Comment: @2A-66-42: Try `echo $x | od -c` to see the hex dump.

Comment: From the doc and with the hex dump I can confirm now that it is a TAB character.

Answer (score 1):

While it may not be necessary in this case, Bash regular expression matching can offer more control over parsing.  For instance, you could have something like this :

```
if
  [[ $output =~ ^[[:space:]]*([^[:space:]]+)[[:space:]]+([^[:space:]]+) ]]
then
  x=${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
  y=${BASH_REMATCH[2]}
else
  # No match
fi
```

This is obviously more complex, but regular expressions can often be used to parse (and extract portions of) strings that have a format that can vary or cannot be handled by `read` due to their structure.

Comment: This works but I'd like to know why sed or read aren't working in this case.

Comment: Your `sed` method works for me, assuming `x="1 2"` to start with.  The `read`-based answer works too.  Your dialog output, which you do not explain what is contains or how it is obtained, probably is the cause it does not work for you.  This being said, while `sed` works, it is a big hammer launching an external prograp and a pipeline just to plus a string.